# RegEx Pattern - accepting what shouldn't be accepted

Tags: java, c#, regex, testing

I know the Title "regex pattern does not work" links to many existing question within Stackoverflow. But I did not find a solution for my issue.

I currently work with the following pattern:

```
^[0-9]$|^[0-9]+[\\.][^\\,][0-9]*$
```

so far so good a friend of mine started explorative testing. We found out that entering the value: 23.a would be accepted. And that should not be the case!

For some reason you can enter everything after the dot. as soon as you enter 23.aa or 23.!a or what ever regex works again.

So in short:
User can enter value 23.a
User can't enter 23.aa

it is strange and I don't understand what's wrong.

thanks for helping.

p.s.
Requirement of my regex:

accepting only numeric values or values whit two digits after the dot. no commas or other characters allowed.

```
23 => 0k
23.1 => ok
23.02 =>
0. = nok
.0 = nok
0, = nok
,0 = nok
```

etc...

Comment: *accepting only numeric values or values whit two digits after the dot.* Why, in that case, is *23.1 => ok*? That only has *one* digit

Comment: If your description is correct, the simple `"\\d+(\\.\\d{2})?"` will do it for you

Comment: @g00se
correction: 1 to max 2 digits after the dot.

Comment: @g00se - by the way. I'm still getting an System.FormatExeption. 
Input String was not in a correct format...

Comment: "*For some reason you can enter everything after the dot.*" reason is `[^\\,]`. Note that `[^...]` is negated character class and it matches all characters *except those which are specified in it*. In other worlds `[^\\,]` represents *any single character except `,`* (``\\`` is considered as escaping which is unnecessary for `,` and ignored).

Comment: That's another problem entirely and probably should be posted separately

Comment: BTW dot `.` inside character `[...]` is ***not*** metacharacter (it has no special meaning) so there is no need to escape it. Instead of `[\\.]` you can/should write `[.]`. Same about comma, which is only "special" inside quantifiers like `{min,}` and `{min,max}`. Outside of them it represents only itself. So `[^\\,]` is same as `[^,]` (but more confusing because of unnecessary ``\\``).

Comment: @Pshemo - great great feedback. 1000 thanks to you. made my weekend.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
"\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?"
```

allows for one or two digits after a decimal point or only an integral number

Comment: I think Anchors are required , could you pls check.

Comment: No, they're not. A Java matching action has to match the whole string

Comment: Thanks again but as mentioned commas are still allowed to be entered. The shouldn't. (if than) only a single . should followed by 1 or two digits or as mentioned an integral number.

Comment: Not the case. What number with one or more commas do you think it allows?

Comment: e.g.
23.1 = can be allowed
23,1 = shall not be allowed

currently
23,1 can be entered. but that makes no sense to me. The pattern shouldn't allow that, right?

Comment: * currently 23,1 can be entered* Please post the code that demonstrates that using the pattern i gave you

Comment: You definitely need the anchors. Otherwise any string containing even one digit *anywhere in it* will be matched [check out this example](https://regex101.com/r/vKsk29/1), then see this one [with the anchors](https://regex101.com/r/9LrJxJ/1) (also note that I used the multi-line flag but that is just for this test and wouldn't be needed). Simply adding anchors to g00se's expression should work for you `"^\\d+(\\.\\d{1,2})?$"`.

Comment: *check out this example* That's not Java. Once more: a pattern match in Java has to match *the whole string*. Only `Pattern.find` searches for matches *inside* strings

Answer (score 0):

```
var pattern = @"^\d+$|^\d+\.\d{1,2}$"
```

Please check this pattern also. Note that it is C# verbatim string (string constants that starts with @ to escape all special characters). The generated output matches with your test.

```
23. =>  False
23 =>  True
23.1 =>  True
23.02 =>  True
0. =>  False
.0 =>  False
0, =>  False
,0 =>  False
23, =>  False
23,1 =>  False
0,0 =>  False
```

Comment: hi - Problem with this pattern is, that commas are still allowed. When I enter 0,0 it's accepted but shouldn't be! So far the digit issue is solved but the issue with the comma isn't

Comment: hi - Issue is not with the pattern , is related to encoding. I am not sure what is Java equivalent for C# verbatim string.